# Jest.config settings modulePathIgnorePatterns and testPathIgnorePatterns aren't having any effect

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm running tests in a `node` app using `jest`. I can get tests running properly, but I can't seem to tell `jest` to ignore directories. For example, when I try to test a specific file `convertExistingImages.ts` with the command: `npm test convertExistingImages` I get a response in my terminal of:

```
> mfa-bot-2022@1.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  dist/utils/maintenance.ts/convertExistingImages.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.
  (...)
 FAIL  src/utils/maintenance/convertExistingImages.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run
  (...)
```

As you can see, a duplicate file in my `/dist` folder is also being tested, which I don't want.

I've tried updating my `jest.config.ts` file as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb",
  "modulePathIgnorePatterns": ["/build/"],
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/", "/build/"]
}
```

But the `modulePathIgnorePatterns` and `testPathIgnorePatterns` settings aren't having any effect.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured it to ignore the `build` folder but your conflict is in the `dist` folder. Change `build` to `dist` in your ignore settings.

You can read more about this config on the [Jest site here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulepathignorepatterns-arraystring).

Comment: Good spot. Looks like a silly error on my part!